# django Charfield suitable for a primary key?

Tags: django-models

In my django model I would like to set the field `unique_id` below to be the primary key as this will be the field used in queries for the model.  It satisfies `unique=True` and `null=False`. However as django sets an AutoField to primary key in the background I'm unsure whether a CharField (which uses a unique 3 character code) is suitable as a primary key or whether this will be sub-optimal?

```
class PaymentMethod(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with setting the `CharField` to be a primary key, by changing the model to be:

```
class PaymentMethod(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=3, primary_key=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

In actual fact if the unique_id is the field you will be querying it makes perfect sense to use it. Your other options are to use your existing model but with `unique=True`:

```
class PaymentMethod(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=3, unique=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

In this case your primary key will be an auto incrementing integer as you previously stated.

Another option depending on the number of records you are looking to store in the `PaymentMethod` models; and where the data is used elsewhere within your application. Is too look into using a [model choices field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#choices). The model choices field might be on your payments or order model (depends on your application and what you are trying to do). This removes the need for a foreignkey and potentially reduces the number of queries in your app.

It could look something like this:

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    VISA = 'VIS'
    CREDIT = 'CRE'
    MASTER_CARD = 'MAS'
    PAYPAL = 'PAL'
    PAYMENT_OPTIONS= (
        (VISA, 'Visa'),
        (CREDIT, 'Credit Card'),
        (MASTER_CARD, 'Master Card'),
        (PAYPAL, 'Paypal')
    )

    items = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    ...
    payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=PAYMENT_OPTIONS, default=VISA)
```

The `PAYMENT_OPTIONS` can be used to render dropdown boxes on the forms when using django [model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/). Otherwise the users selection is limited to the options listed within this model.
This method would be a lot more efficient if you only have a small subset of `PaymentMethod(s)`.

Comment: Thanks I notice you haven't specified `primary_key=True` in the choices option. Does using choices make this redundant?  I only have 5 choices for this field, so this may be a good option, however does using choices automatically make an index or is it more efficient in another way.  I've also just seen that setting `unique=True` automatically creates an index so between the first 2 options (primary key or just using unique) is there much difference?

Comment: If you do the choices route then you will create a column in the model where you would normally have the foreignkey to `PaymentMethod`. Basically anywhere you would do `payment_type=models.ForeignKey(PaymentMethod)` you would instead do `payment_choice=models.CharField(...., choices=<list payment choices>). Basically no need for PaymentMethod model at all.

Comment: Brilliant that's ideal thanks. I have another similar model with only 3 choices, however it is possible to have more than one option. Is that possible to bring into the model or does it have to be a separate M2M model too?

Answer (score 9):

It's possible to use `CharField` as primary key. You just have to mark the field as primary key.

```
field_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
```

**But I wouldn't recommend it** because:

- Primary keys are used in urls (typically in Rest APIs) - but not all characters are allowed in urls
- DRF (django-rest-framework) use urls patterns that don't catch some characters by default (for example ".")
- Primary keys must be unique - it's harder to accomplish it if the field is a string, especially when you let users to define it

Comment: CharFields must define a 'max_length' attribute.

Comment: While syntactically correct, I would suggest against a varchar(100) primary key. From what I've read, things start to get inefficient beyond the 10-20 range.